# How to make Xamarin.Forms change size of my custom control on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

My custom control can sometimes change its size. In this case I call `RequestLayout` and `Invalidate`. Then in `OnMeasure` I call `SetMeasuredDimension` with new height. But here I face two issues:

1. `OnMeasure` is called with `MeasureSpecMode.Exact`.
2. Even if I ignore `MeasureSpecMode` and call `SetMeasuredDimension` with new values control size stays the same.

So my question is if there is a way to tell Forms layout engine to update my controls size?

**EDIT:**
It is possible to force Forms to update layout by hiding and then showing the control but I'm looking for a less hacky way to fix this.

Comment: Can you show the code for your custom control? What kind of control did you derive your custom control from? If it is a `ContentView` for example, you could call `ForceLayout()` but sometime sizing issues like this stem from a problem with your layout.

Comment: My control is derived from ImageView. Code is here - https://github.com/halkar/xamarin-range-slider/blob/master/Xamarin.RangeSlider.Droid/RangeSliderControl.cs Page is here - https://github.com/halkar/xamarin-range-slider/blob/master/Xamarin.RangeSlider.Forms.Samples/Xamarin.RangeSlider.Forms.Samples/MainPage.xaml

Comment: If you are using Xamarin Forms then you would be using [this](https://github.com/halkar/xamarin-range-slider/blob/master/Xamarin.RangeSlider.Forms/RangeSlider.cs) file in the shared project which derives from `View`which does not have the `ForceLayout()` method. I still think it would help to see the Xamarin Forms code where you instantiate the custom control and where you add it to a layout so that we can see what sizing options are being used.

Comment: XAML is here https://github.com/halkar/xamarin-range-slider/blob/master/Xamarin.RangeSlider.Forms.Samples/Xamarin.RangeSlider.Forms.Samples/MainPage.xaml

Comment: And ForceLayout doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If we are really talking about Forms and not xamarin.android you can check about how it works here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom

So basically inside your Forms control after you have calculated the size you desire call `InvalidateMeasure();`
Override `OnMeasure` and pass the desired size, Forms will do the rest:

```
//fields used to store the desired size
private double _widthRequest = -1;
private double _heightRequest = -1;

    protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        if (_widthRequest > 0 && _heightRequest > 0)
        {
            var wish = new Size(_widthRequest, _heightRequest);
            _widthRequest = -1;
            _heightRequest = -1;
            return new SizeRequest(wish);
        }

        return base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
    }
```